How to apply a shader texture to a GLB model element while preserving the native GLB texture?
I have a GLB model and I want to apply a shader texture to it in three.js
But I want to preserve the texture of the model that was created in Blender
Unfortunately, the shader completely overwrites the texture, and I need it to lay on top of the native GLB texture
How to do it?
Here is my shader material
 i3d_glob.customShaderMaterial = new THREE.ShaderMaterial({
 uniforms: {
 tDiffuse: { value: inputTexture },
 tDepth: { value: null },
 thickness: { value: 1.5 },
 color: { value: new THREE.Color('#f00') },
 SCREEN_WIDTH: { value: i3d_glob.SCREEN_WIDTH },
 SCREEN_HEIGHT: { value: i3d_glob.SCREEN_HEIGHT },
 resolution: { value: new THREE.Vector2(window.innerWidth, window.innerHeight) },
 u_resolution: { value: new THREE.Vector2(window.innerWidth, window.innerHeight) },
 u_originalMaterial: { value: null },
 u_time: { value: 0.0 },
 },
 vertexShader: shd.vertexShader,
 fragmentShader: shd.fragmentShader,
 vertexColors: true,
 })

As I read on the Internet, one of the possible solutions is here
tDiffuse: { value: inputTexture },
Instead of inputTexture, put the desired texture
If I load a simple image, it works, the shader is superimposed on top of the image
But I need a texture from GLB
I opened GLB in Blender and I see (in the screenshot) that each element of the model has its own texture, but there are a lot of elements, I will not be able to copy them all and save them
How can I programmatically get the desired GLB texture and substitute it in tDiffuse?
Or maybe there is a better way?
Blender GLB screenshot
